# PHP question: Is it possible to add an array value in a SQL query to establish dynamic filters?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I would like to display the sports clubs that offer the type of sports a user selected. So far I've done the following:

1. I added the filters to the page:

[Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu94w.png)

2. For the types of sports, I've created the array 'typefilter' via name="typefilter[]"

   Adventure
                            
                            Climbing
                            
                            Crossfit
                            
                            Cycling
                            
                            Kitesurfing
                            
                            Martial arts
                            
                            Multi-sports
                            
                            Pilates
                            
                            Rugby
                            
                            Running
                            
                            Swimming
                            
                            Tennis
                            
                            Triathlon
                            
                            Yoga
3. I checked that the selected items are appearing in the array and that works:

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9IB8.png)

4. JOIN tables

I have a table with Organizations, and a table with Types, and also a Location table. The name of the sports are the name of the columns in the Types database:

[types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuNF8.png)

When I select the organization info via the following query, it works when I have 'adventure' hardcoded in the query:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_x_organizations
        JOIN wp_x_types ON wp_x_types.organization = wp_x_organizations.organization
        JOIN wp_x_location ON wp_x_location.organization = wp_x_organizations.organization
        WHERE wp_x_types.adventure = 1");
        ?>
```

The issue is, I want 'adventure' to be the value of the typefilter[] array. And even better if there is a loop or so, where all organizations with all selected sports types are shown in the results table.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: So if user selected `adventure` and `climbing` you want the query to have `WHERE wp_x_types,adventure=1 OR wp_x_types.climbing=1` ?

Comment: @ITgoldman, yes, correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use php to construct the sql string.

```php
$arr = ['climbing', 'adventure', 'multi-sports'];
$arr_where = array_map(function($item) {
    return "wp_x_types.`$item` = 1";
}, $arr);
$str_where = "(" . implode (' OR ', $arr_where) . ")";
// echo $str_where;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_x_organizations
        JOIN wp_x_types ON wp_x_types.organization = wp_x_organizations.organization
        JOIN wp_x_location ON wp_x_location.organization = wp_x_organizations.organization
        WHERE $str_where";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out! When I add the following code, no results are coming up. Do I need to replace anything?

$arr = ['climbing', 'adventure', 'multi-sports'];
            $arr_where = array_map(function($item) {
                return "wp_x_types.`$item` = 1";
            }, $arr);
            $str_where = "(" . implode (' OR ', $arr_where) . ")";
            // echo $str_where;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_x_organizations WHERE " . $str_where . " ";
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

Comment: See the `$arr = ['climbing', 'adventure', 'multi-sports']` you need to replace that array with the array of `$_REQUEST['typefilter']` or something like that.